# Code structure and necessary elements in web development

Tags: php, html, css, web, structure

I'm thinking of developing a database-based web application from scratch but I have some concerns. I'm quite new to the world of web development (I've done Harvard's course CS50, but that's about as far as my knowledge goes) and I've recently tried wordpress a bit.

Something that confuses me is how many different files, how extremely much css and how many different nested divs there are in most wordpress themes, but also on any website in general. This makes me anxious, since I feel like I will miss so many things by starting from scratch.

My questions are basically:

1. Are all the css rules, nested html divs and php-code necessary or are they to some extent a product of copy-paste (in the case of wordpress themes specifically). If they are necessary, what does it all do? Could someone give me a brief overview of the thousands of lines of css and tens of php-files?
2. What are the best practices when building a website from scratch? How should the structure of the html look like (especially considering nested divs), how should I build up the css file and what code is important to include? I guess I'm looking for an explanation of the structure of development and a description of a template of code (html, css and php) that you should always include.

I'm planning on building a serious, secure and well-functional web-application and that's why I want to follow the best practices and understand the purpose of all the code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `I'm planning on building a serious, secure and well-functional web-application` - then don't use Wordpress as an inspiration or an example, just don't.

Comment: LOL! sry i just had to... *g* Buddy, you have to figure out these things on your own, by this you will build out a personal habit how you overcome obstacles and how you get information you need. we cant just explain to you in 3 lines how web development (or wordpress) works... but: yes, usually all these CSS-classes and divs are necessary. build something on your own and you will realize.

Answer (score 0):

1) CSS rules can be nested and can also be simplified in many ways.  CSS can be implemented by tags, classes, ids, and others.  Best way is to read and understand each one and when to use them.  They are simpler than Wordpress makes it.

2) To start a new project, start by understanding the scope of your project and know what your objective is.  Once you have that, start to design your database with tables and relations.  After that, look for frameworks that would help you get started.  Take into consideration that you will want to seporate your code to organize it.  When working with database I like to split my code into MVC.  This allows me to keep organized and reuse code well.  There are a number of tools out there that will help you get up and running really fast.  Take a look at Yii development.  It has a tool called gii that takes your database and creates code for you to get started.  It creates a lot of helpful views as well.   Other helpful tools would be twitter bootstrap and jquery for your visual needs.  They are easy to use javascript plugins and css frameworks to get you off the ground.

I hope this helps